# Qual è il significato di "cozzeca" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Sí, sí, giurava Cichitto, e intanto si grattava – tanto che, a forza di grattarsi con le unghie sporche, la sua pelle si era piagata, una superficie rossa di **cozzeca**, tutta pustole e croste – e tossiva, squassato da una tosse violenta, che gli nasceva dall’anima.

Come indicato nei commenti qui sotto, alcuni dizionari riportano "còzzeca" come variante regionale di "cozza". Tuttavia, nel contesto del brano sopra citato, questo significato non sembra avere molto senso, soprattutto perché si afferma che si trattava di una "superficie rossa". Per questa ragione vi chiedo: potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "cozzeca" nel contesto di questo testo? Immagino si tratti di un termine regionale, possibilmente derivato dal napoletano.

Comment: Su Garzanti per [cozzeca](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=cozzeca) viene dato come significato cozza. Anche per [Hoepli](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/cozzeca.html). [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cozza_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) lo riporta nei sinonimi e contrari come variante regionale di cozza.

Comment: Anche lo Zingarelli lo registra come variante di “cozza”.

Comment: @abarisone: Hai ragione! Ma ha qualche senso "cozza" nel contesto del testo?

Comment: Probabilmente si era talmente grattato che la sua pelle ricordava la superficie esterna della valva di una cozza.

Comment: @abarisone: Anche se era rossa poteva assomigliare a una cozza?

Comment: @Charo Quella che assomigliava alla superficie della cozza era la pelle piagata di Cichitto

Comment: @abarisone:  Sì, lo so, ma il testo dice "una superficie rossa di cozzeca".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nell'articolo di Luigi Matt 
 intitolato 
*[Chi è stregato dallo Strega? Rilievi di stile sugli ultimi romanzi vincitori (2002-2009)](https://www.torrossa.com/gs/resourceProxy?an=2463930&publisher=FR1090)* ho trovato:

> 101); zezzilli capezzoli” (p. 107); lorcia “sudiciume” (p. 109);
>   scamuso “molto magro” (p. 113); alleccamussi “ceffoni” (p. 113, 176);
>   ***cozzeca “crosta di una ferita”***

In questo *[Vocabolario domestico napoletano e toscano](https://books.google.es/books?id=ICrennDu0x8C&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=cozzeca%20crosta&source=bl&ots=aifD7d2797&sig=ACfU3U1liyW1UCXNOtA5CTUSl705rfWA7A&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjyo-g37njAhUxDWMBHf64Cg0Q6AEwBHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=cozzeca%20crosta&f=false)* si può trovare il termine cozzeca:

> **COZZECA**: sost. femm. Quella crosta che si fa su la carne ulcerata.

Il termine ***cozzeca*** sembra quindi indicare la crosta di una ferita.

Comment: Grazie, @abarisone! Ho modificato il testo della domanda perché penso che così abbia più senso e anche perché adesso me n'accorgo che l'accezione di "còzzeca" come "cozza" veramente l'avevo vista ma, pensando che non aveva senso nel contesto del testo, l'avevo completamente dimenticata. Il problema è che avevo letto questo brano alcuni giorni fa, ma solo oggi mi sono decisa a porre la domanda. Prima di farlo ho cercato sul vocabolario Treccani e sul Battaglia e ho visto che là questa voce non c'era.

Comment: Appare anche su [questo dizionario](https://books.google.es/books?id=ICrennDu0x8C&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=cozzeca+crosta&source=bl&ots=aifD7d2797&sig=ACfU3U1liyW1UCXNOtA5CTUSl705rfWA7A&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjyo-g37njAhUxDWMBHf64Cg0Q6AEwBHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=cozzeca%20crosta&f=false): se vuoi, puoi includerlo nella risposta.